# Changing the datatype with a custom type in postgres custom data type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a custom type in Postgres DB called `money_with_currency` Created as:

```sql
CREATE TYPE public.money_with_currency AS (currency_code char(3), amount numeric);
```

We want to change the type of `currency_code` from `char(3)` to `varchar`.

I thought the code would be something like:

```
ALTER TYPE public.money_with_currency ALTER ATTRIBUTE currency_code SET DATA TYPE varchar;
```

But got an error:

```
  ALTER TYPE public.money_with_currency ALTER ATTRIBUTE currency_code SET DATA TYPE varchar;\n"
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 0A000 (feature_not_supported) cannot alter type "money_with_currency" because column "prog_fees.amount" uses it
```

Any thoughts if there is a solution without having to do manual migration to all columns using the type?

Comment: This is because prog_fees amount column  currently use this custom type.And may be data in that column could not convert to new type.

Comment: @YJR the old type is `char(3)` and the new one is `varchar`. Why wouldn't it covert?

Comment: @Tam that is because it could not convert column at once you alter the type.I add some steps to the answer try it. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

First create another custom type and use an alter table query to change the column type of the prog_fees. Then alter the  type of public.money_with_currency. Then again execute a alter query to table using public.money_with_currency type. Then it will work

Comment: Not sure if I got what you mean, but I will run into the same issue because it will try to cast the column to the new column type. For instance, I can create new type: `CREATE TYPE public.money_with_currency_1 AS (currency_code varchar, amount numeric);` But then doing `ALTER COLUMN amount TYPE money_with_currency_1` will throw an error: `ERROR:  cannot cast type money_with_currency to money_with_currency_1`

Comment: That is bcause automatic casting not work. Use this way. ALTER TABLE the_table ALTER COLUMN col_name TYPE <TYPE> USING(trim(col_name)::<TYPE>)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new type with the desired structure. But as there is no direct cast from the old to the new type, you need to use a row constructor when altering the type of the existing column:

```
CREATE TYPE money_with_currency_new AS (currency_code text, amount numeric);

alter table prog_fees
  alter column amount type money_with_currency_new 
  using ((amount).currency_code, (amount).amount)::money_with_currency_new;
```

Note the parentheses around the column name when referencing the type's attributes. They are required.

After that you can drop the old type and rename the new type to the old name:

```
drop type money_with_currency;

alter type money_with_currency_new
  rename to money_with_currency;
```